# From $5$ apples, $4$ mangoes and $3$ bananas, in how many ways we can select at least two fruits of each variety?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> From $5$ apples, $4$ mangoes and $3$ bananas, in how many ways we can select at least two fruits of each variety if fruits of same species are different?

My attempts:

$$\underbrace{\bigg({5\choose 2}+{5\choose 3}+{5\choose 4}+{5\choose 5}\bigg)}_{\text{appples}}\cdot\underbrace{\bigg({4\choose 2}+{4\choose 3}+{4\choose 4}\bigg)}_\text{mangoes}\cdot\underbrace{\bigg({3\choose 2}+{3\choose 3}\bigg)}_\text{bananas}=1144$$

But answer is: $2^{12}-4$. Please help.

Comment: $2^{12}-4$ cannot be right. There are only $2^{12}$ ways to select fruits _without_ the "at least two of each kind" restriction, and many more than $4$ of those are excluded by this restriction -- e.g. all the $12$ ways to select a _single_ fruit only.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Where did you find the answer was $2^{12}-4$? If it doesn't show you how, you should believe in your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  We can confirm it with another approach.

The number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements is $2^n$ since each element is either included in a subset or it is not.

Since there are $5$ apples, there are $2^5$ subsets of apples.  Of these, $\binom{5}{0} + \binom{5}{1} = 1 + 5 = 6$ have fewer than two apples. Thus, $2^5 - 6 = 32 - 6 = 26$ have at least two apples.

Since there are four mangoes, there are $2^4$ subsets of mangoes.  Of these, $\binom{4}{0} + \binom{4}{1} = 1 + 4 = 5$ have fewer than two mangoes.  Thus, $2^4 - 5 = 16 - 5 = 11$ have at least two mangoes.

Since there are three bananas, there are $2^3$ subsets of bananas.  Of these, $\binom{3}{0} + \binom{3}{1} = 1 + 3 = 4$ have fewer than two bananas.  Thus, $2^3 - 4 = 8 - 4 = 4$ have at least two bananas.

Hence, the number of ways of selecting at least two fruits of each variety is 
$$26 \cdot 11 \cdot 4 = 1144$$
as you found.